# Complex series doesnt converge absolutely

Tags: complex-analysis

The series $\sum_{n = 1}^{\infty} a_{n}$ with $a_{n} = \frac{1}{\sqrt n - i n}$ does not converge absolutely because, $$|a_{n}| = \frac{1}{|\sqrt n - i n|} = \frac{1}{\sqrt{n + n^2}} \geq \frac{1}{\sqrt 2 \ n } $$ and $\frac{1}{\sqrt 2}\sum_{n=1}^{\infty} \frac{1}{n}$ does not converge.

Therefore the ratio test and other comparison tests dont work. 
My question is, if this series does converge or if it diverges.
I dont managed to show if the series is either a cauchy sequence or not

Comment: You are correct.  It does not converge absolutely.  In fact, it does not converge at all.

Comment: Im sure there are converging series that dont converge absolutely

Comment: $\sum\frac{(-1)^n}{n}$ converges, but not absolutely.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

$$\frac{1}{\sqrt{n}-in} = \frac{\sqrt{n}}{n+n^2}+i\frac{n}{n+n^2} $$
From the definition of a complex series, it doesn't converge, since it's imaginary part doesn't converge. ($\frac{n}{n+n^2} $ is comparable with $\frac{1}{n}$ and $\sum \frac{1}{n} $ doesn't converge)

Comment: When the absolute value of a complex number (in your case of the denominator of the summand) comes out negative, you can be pretty sure that you have made a mistake.

Comment: @AlexB. Thank you